# Can this be written more succinctly (preferably as an eigenequation)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, differential-operators

I have the set of equations $$\pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z}=\pmatrix{\partial_xL_x &\partial_yL_x &\partial_zL_x \\ \partial_xL_y &\partial_yL_y &\partial_zL_y \\ \partial_xL_z &\partial_yL_z &\partial_zL_z} \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}$$

I feel like this should be expressible in terms of the vectors $$L=\pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ L_z}\!, \;\;r=\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z}\!,$$ some differential operators (like the gradient or the divergence) and perhaps a matrix with some zeros and ones, but I've been unable to come up with anything yet.

**Any ideas?**

Ideally one would be able to write it like some vector DE whose solutions could be said something intelligent about, but this may not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations for $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ are independent and equal. Writing $L_x = u$, you obtain
\begin{equation}
 u = r \cdot\nabla u  = x\, u_x + y\, u_y + z\, u_z.
\end{equation}
You can easily solve this first order linear partial differential equation using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).